# Static Classes, Good or Bad?

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, static

I have read something's, about `static` classes, mostly about that static classes are "evil" in Java, and I was wondering what does the `Static` calss actually do?

What are the applications to it Unity C#, and C# in general?

Comment: why are they "evil" in Java exactly? It depends on the use.

Comment: Everything (`goto` included) can be good or evil.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Although `goto` is hard to justify :)

Comment: In Unity3d I recommend Scriptable Objects.

Comment: @Lotan I have read some stuff like this, this one was just a question, but still https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil     But my question is not why about Java, more towards C#

Comment: @PandaStrong but why?

Comment: Note that the question you linked to is very old. These kinds of questions no longer are considered a good fit for SO, because their answers have to be based on opinion and thus they lead to discussion more than to subjectively correct answers.

Comment: 1. Changes during playn mode are preserved.
2. You can easily drag&drop them everywhere and get the same effect as static.
3. serialization

Comment: @JoachimSauer Okay thanks, I just started to learn coding, so I don't know what is considered "old" or new

Comment: @DmitryBychenko what is "goto"

Comment: `goto` is a notorious statemed (now we use `if`, `switch`, `while`, `for`, `return` instead) which has been considered harmful by Dijkstra in year 1968 https://homepages.cwi.nl/~storm/teaching/reader/Dijkstra68.pdf

Comment: @PandaStrong Note that "Changes during play mode are preserved" won't be allways the desired behaviour for static classes.

Answer (score 1):

"*The `static` modifier makes an item non-instantiable, it means the static item cannot be instantiated. If the static modifier is applied to a class then that class cannot be instantiated using the `new` keyword. If the static modifier is applied to a variable, method or property of class then they can be accessed without creating an object of the class, just use `className.propertyName`, `className.methodName`.*"

Static class basically means that there is just one instance of the object.

It can be good or bad, depends on what you need, for example if you have an `int` to store the player money you can use `static int money` and then `get` or `set` the variable
from anywhere, but if you want to create something multiple time (like enemies etc') you cann't use it.

[Here is a link to read more about the Static class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members)